# How does Git reflect changes from its objects onto the file system?

Tags: git, version-control

I've gone through the [Git Internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals) book and mostly understand how Git structures things into blobs, trees, commits and that branches are lightweight pointers to commits.

The part I don't quite grasp is how Git reflects these changes onto the file system across branch/commit checkouts.

For example:

Consider two files, `A.txt` and `B.txt`, committed to `Commit 1`. In addition to the two files, a file `C.txt`  is committed to `Commit 2`.

From what I understand, the object graph would be along the lines of the following:

1. `Commit 1` points to `Tree 1` which has blobs for the two initial files - `BlobA` and `BlobB`
2. `Commit 2` points to `Tree 2` which has blobs for three files. `BlobA` and `BlobB` remain the same since their content has not changed, while `BlobC` will also be under `Tree 2`.

Now, if I'm currently at `Commit 2` and checkout to `Commit 1`, `HEAD` now points to `Commit 1`, and we can traverse the directed graph that tells the state of the repository. Now, the file `C.txt` is no longer on the file system.

How does Git reflect the state of the object graph onto the file system on every checkout?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what does you mean with *How does Git reflect the state of the object graph onto the file system?*. You know the difference between working dir and .git dir?

Comment: @ErniBrown Of course. In the question, the file system is referring to the working directory. How does Git determine that file `C.txt` should be removed (mutatis mutandis to any number of files). Is there any diff-ing going on between the graphs from the source commit and the destination commit. I couldn't find resources for this

Comment: It determines to remove `C.txt` because it's in the tree of `Commit 2`, but not in the tree of `Commit 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Git's work-tree actions are actually controlled via the *index*.  This means no graph traversal is required at all!

The index's primary role (outside of merges at least) is to act as the place in which you build up the *next* commit to make.  This gives it the name that many people prefer to use, the *staging area*.  In the index, the version of a file such as `README.txt` will start out matching the `HEAD` version of that same file.  Both files are actually stored as a *blob* object in the repository.

The work-tree will contain a usable version of `README.txt`, representing the expanded version of the file.  This is also smudge-filtered and CRLF-adjusted, if you have established such filtering.  If you change the work-tree version, and wish to commit the changes, you must run `git add README.txt`: this copies the work-tree file back into the index, applying any clean filter and doing the CRLF-to-LF adjustment if you have those enabled, creating a new blob in the repository (or re-using an existing blob if the new file content matches some existing content) and storing the new hash into the index.  In effect, this replaces the index copy of the file.

So far so good—but what happens when you have some commit checked out, e.g., as the result of `git checkout master`, and you issue the command `git checkout develop`?  Here, the index takes on its second role, which is to keep track of—i.e., index—the work-tree and to keep cache information about the work-tree.  (This is also the source of its third name, the *cache*.)

Git already translated `master` into a commit hash to extract that commit, but at this point it does so again.  At this point, Git is using the so-called *two tree merge* mode of the `git read-tree` command.  It also translates `develop` into a commit hash, so now it has two commit hashes, for `master` (current commit) and `develop` (desired commit).  After making sure that these are indeed commits,<sup>1</sup> Git translates them into tree hash IDs: the `HEAD` tree, and the desired or target tree.

Meanwhile the *index* lists the hash ID for each tracked file in the work-tree.  In the ideal case, for each file *F* in the index and/or in the `HEAD` commit, *F* will have the same hash in both `HEAD` and index.  If so, the index copy of `F` is itself "clean" (matches).  The work-tree copy may or may not be clean (may or may not match the index copy)—the index's role as *cache* here helps make this last test very fast in most cases.

For each file *F* that exists in *both* `HEAD` *and* the target tree, either the target hash for *F* matches the `HEAD` hash for `F`, or it doesn't.  For files that *do not* exist in the target tree, but do exist in `HEAD`, either the index and work-tree copy of *F* are clean, or they're not.  If the file is clean, it's safe to remove both copies (if the file is not in the target) or replace both with the version from the target tree (if the file is in the target).  But if the target tree hash *matches* the `HEAD` hash, there is no need to touch the index and work-tree entry at all, so Git doesn't.

In short, it's only where `HEAD` and target trees *don't* match that Git needs to change anything in the work-tree to achieve the checkout.  If the part that does not match is that file `xyz.txt` is in `HEAD` but not in the target, the goal becomes *remove `xyz.txt`*—but this is only allowed if it is "clean", unless of course you add `--force` to your `git checkout`.  If the part that does not match is that the file is in neither `HEAD` nor the index, but *is* in the target, the goal becomes to *create* `xyz.txt` with the target's content—but this is only allowed if the file does not exist, or if the file is listed in an ignore directive.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Branch names are required to identify commit hashes at all times.  (Tag names are permitted to identify other types of objects.)  So in theory there is no need to check this.  Whether Git really does check, depends on the code path.

<sup>2</sup>This last part is the source of some serious pain at times.  Git really should—but does not—distinguish between "ignore this file because it's easy to re-create" and "ignore this file because it should not be committed, but *never clobber it* because it contains something precious like user configuration data."